# i am trying to use Voice input in my android application but when i m clicking on the button it breaks the activity

Tags: android

i am trying to use Voice input in my android application but when i am clicking on the button it show google voice input popup but in result of voice input it breaks the current activity . can some body tell me what will be the problem in my code is there any library which i am missing .

Comment: Post your logcat and sufficient code to get a better idea about your error and code

Comment: thank you for your reply ,it was resolved :) . i was using no history with the activity that's why it was breaking .